# Illustrator vector aliasing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, anti-aliasing

How can I make my vector graphics anti-aliased in illustrator? My paths always turn out jagged. Is there an option like in Adobe Fireworks to smoothen[remove the jaged edges] my paths?

Comment: can you show a sample? Is anti-aliasing checked in the Illustrator preferences? Possible duplicate of [Illustrator Vector Graphics Appearing Pixellated](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16028/illustrator-vector-graphics-appearing-pixellated)

Comment: Same problem. Upgraded to CC2015 from CC2014. Anti-aliasing ticked in General preferences. On screen, all the paths are jagged and so annoying that I've now started working in CS5! (CC2015 over written CC2014, which anti-aliased ok).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Edit > Preferences > General there is an option that toggles Anti-Aliasing for art as it is displayed on screen while you work.

Under Effect > Document Raster Effect Settings there is a checkbox for Anti-Aliasing that controls to some degree the outcome of the file once it is saved to a non-vector format (ie. jpg, gif, png).

Depending on which file type you save to there are often more options that can affect the appearance of jagged lines in your art. What you are saving can influence how you should use these settings, as you may want to do things that may seem counter intuitive. Small type for example may need no or very little anti-aliasing or it will become muddy. Also take into consideration the PPI of the file. Low resolution images will appear have jagged edges even with anti-aliasing—the human eye can detect up to 150 ppi, at 72 ppi the pixels will not resolve at a normal viewing distance.

Comment: But this is for when you place raster's within Illustrator, right?.. Not for the actual vectors?

Comment: I was under the impression that it applied to all art. Since Illustrator has to rasterize all the art in order to display it I would assume it was running these anti-aliasing algorithms on everything. But that is simply my logical conclusion on the matter.

Comment: Without knowing when the "jagged edges" are introduced it might be that his Document Raster Ëffects Settings are the source of the problem he has. There is also an Anti-Alias option in that menu as well. Some quick checking confirms that the Edit > Preferences > General > Anti-Alias option does affect the appearance of vectors on screen as you work with them. The Effect > Document Raster Effects Settings > Anti-Alias affects the art as it is saved to another (rasterized) format. But even with anti-aliasing a low resolution (72ppi) will be jagged even at no zoom.

Comment: ![My design logo Alex_graphics][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yzqpW.png

That is the image I was referencing and well, I appreciate it seems the problem was linked to "he Effect > Document Raster Effects Settings > Anti-Alias affects" settings. Saved my time :)

Comment: @BoscoMabutao If this answer worked for you, can you mark it as 'Accepted' with the tick icon, so we know the problem is solved and others can see which answer worked?

Answer (score 12):

If you are having aliasing problems in Illustrator CC 2015, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> toggles between GPU and CPU previewing. CPU's anti-aliasing is 1000% better.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. In one of the latest updates, my vectors started looking jagged. ⌘+E solved that problem! Thank you!

Comment: This should be the answer to the question. Worked like a charm.

Comment: After some scrolling or zooming, if it looks messed up even with CPU rendering, you may need to enable "CPU Pixel Preview" with (Ctrl/Cmd)+(Alt/Option)+Y. Use the same shortcut to get out of the "Pixel Preview" and return to regular CPU or GPU preview. You can view the current rendering mode in the document tab name.

Answer (score 0):

Vector graphics do not have anti-aliasing as they are not raster graphics. If you have jagged edges, it might be your display performance setting. I've seen that in InDesign, not sure if it exists in Illustrator at all, actually.

If you are talking about when you import or paste your vector into Photoshop and it produces jagged edges there, that's a different question entirely.

Please provide a screenshot if you can.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid jagged lines when you "Save for Web & Devices" in the tab "Image Size" set combo box at the bottom to "Art optimized" or "Type optimized" depending on the content of your image (by default this combo box is set to "None").