# Place psd file into Illustrator without losing quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, image-quality

I want import a psd file into Illustrator without losing quality.

I have a 300dpi image at Photoshop with height 60 cm, as you can see below.

[image]
(You can see a smooth "D")

I create an Illustrator document with height 100cm and "Raster Effects: 300 ppi".
[image]

But when I "File/Place" the .psd file i get the below result.
[image]

The photo in Illustrator loss quality.
Why this happens?

How can I place psd file into Illustrator with best quality?

Thank you.

Comment: The preview is probably not the best place to evaluate the quality - your screen density is probably low and the placed image may be a low quality placeholder. Note though that by placing a 60cm high image in a 100cm high space (whilst keeping the pixel count the same), you are actually reducing the DPI by about 40%. You have kept the Dots the same and increased the inches, so the dots-per-inch becomes smaller.

Comment: Why even use Photoshop for that? But this may answer your question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16030/3270

Comment: Hi Fotis, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

I can't really say why your having a problem with that, but I suppose the best way to maintain quality is to not embed the image at all.

When you do a Place make sure the `Link` checkbox is checked.

[image]

The image will remain a PSD file, and the representation you see in Illustrator will just be a preview, so no quality can be lost until you export to something else from Illustrator.

Answer (score -1):

Save your photoshop file as photoshop pdf, and in the pdf settings (very important) **change the compression setting to none**, this should give you the best file to manage in illustrator.

Comment: I'm not sure why adding an *additional* file wrapper such as PDF would be seen as "better". Illustrator is perfectly capable of placing native .psd files and there's no more compression than standard .psd files use.