# Fill a vector path in Photoshop CS5 without pixelated edges

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, path, fill

I've created a smooth path around an image that I'd like to vectorize. Now I'd like to fill that path to make it a solid with smooth edges.

1. I created a new layer
2. I selected the path and the new layer
3. I clicked on "fill path with foreground color" at the bottom of the path window

The path is filled, but the lines are jaggy. What am I missing in order to make the edges smooth and crisp - i.e. vectorized?

Comment: While this answer relates to Illustrator, it may help explain a bit: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16028/illustrator-vector-graphics-appearing-pixellated/16030#16030

Comment: What colour mode are you using? **Image** > **Mode**  There should be an option ticked. Make sure this is **RGB Color** or another of the alternatives.

Comment: Also what is the image size? If you try to do it in a very small object the  lines will look jagged (or if you zoom in too close)

Answer (score 1):

Filling a path can make slight "jaggynes". For the pixelation goes, it all depends on the resolution of your document, remeber that photoshop documents isnt vectorbased in the same fashion that Illustrator, and that you cant get the same scaling.

When choosing the path tool, make sure to chose the shape tool in the drop down menu. [image]

Comment: it's not about the resolution, but the size in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `Path tool` to create a path, a popup button in the options bar dictates if it will create a path (shown in the paths panel), or a shape layer. If you’d like to create a filled shape, this should be set to `Shape`.

[image: Photoshop options bar]

If you created a path instead, that’s okay. You’ll know you’ve done this, because the paths panel will show an item called `Work path`.

[image: Paths panel in Photoshop]

Choosing `Layer` → `New Fill Layer` → `Solid Color` will create a solid fill shape layer using the path you’ve just created. If the result is the inverse of what you’d like, choosing the `Combine Shapes` from the boolean menu in the options bar will fix it.

[image: Photoshop boolean shape options]

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop specifically, you need to use the pen tool to create vector shapes. You can also use the shape tools and choose a fill color. The marquee tools (i.e. lasso, rectangle, circle or magic wand) will always have a pixelated edge when zooming in. If plan to work exclusively with vector shapes you will want to work with Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

Select your path, then in layer panel in lower right corner select create new fill/ adjustment layer and select solid color.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, but the answer is really simple. You just have to tick the **Anti-alias** option under the Feather Radius in the **Fill Path** window.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I think you are confused with **path** and **shape**. If you work with shapes you can add fill and/or stroke as you want with pixel-perfect results.
Paths are commonly used for masks, cut-out paths and similar.
Try to convert your path into a shape and then edit from the top menu as indicated in image.
Check also the adobe help about [drawing shapes](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-shapes.html#shape_tool_options).

[image: Shape fill and stroke]

Comment: No, the OP knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score -2):

I found this because I am having the same problem....haven't tried it yet, will do first thing in the morning. I hope this helps you too....hope it works!

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-creating-crisp-pixel-perfect-circles-in-photoshop--webdesign-9330

Answer (score -3):

The best is using Illustrator and copy paste to Photoshop as smart object. Any editing done in Illustrator will be real time update in photoshop.

Comment: No - the OP is using Photoshop and needs an answer to the question posted.