# How to draw smooth curved shapes in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

I did one illustration like this. It includes thin curved lines. I took lot of time and patience to create this one. But the end result is looking a bit cluttered. I'm expecting very smooth curves. How can I make these curves smoother in Illustrator.

[image]

Comment: Do you think you could upload a bigger image? It's a bit hard to see the details with the low quality image and its small size...! It's also possible the only answer you'll get will be "keep going until it's perfect!" And do you mean the Illustrator file should look smoother or your png when you export at this size?

Comment: That is the exported Png image. I'm expecting the exported file to be smoother. not the illustrator file. and yes I'm trying it, I just want to know any techniques which can be used, I'm new to illustrator

Comment: Are you using the hinted or art oprimized option in save for web. The art optimized should be smoother.

Comment: Thanks @joojaa, It looks a bit smoother now. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16028/illustrator-vector-graphics-appearing-pixellated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There certainly is room for improvement in Adobes anti-aliasing routines. Adobe is not a big DSP shop and really does not need to follow the latest in the development of algorithms. In terms of what science tells us one could do better. For example one could use [Lanczos filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling) on the multi pixel sample. In addition filtering should be done in a linear color space, then converted back to nonlinear sRGB for example.

[image]

**Image 1**: Art optimized done in Illustrator (left), and linear Lanczos filtered (right)*

Now adobe seems to use bicubic filtering which is almost comparable to Lanczos overall, which one you prefer is ultimately up to you. The non linearity in filter spreads the lines wider and make them look pixelated. Bear in mind due to the fact that adobe uses the non corrected preview then your lines will be a bit thinner, once corrected.

* used following imagemagick command on a 1600% image with no AA:

```
convert artopt2.png -colorspace RGB ^
                    -filter Lanczos -resize 175 ^
                    -colorspace sRGB ^
        out.png
```

Comment: This is just fantastic. I'm not familiar with Imagemagick. Almost I spent 3 hours to setup and make it work. After executing this command, really I felt surprise. Thanks alot @joojaa