# remove white-space from blend while maintaining lines as strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, clipping-mask

I am trying to make a laser cut pattern in illustrator and I want to make the following image etched into wood (red lines etched). 
[image]

So, here is the rub. Right now those lines are just a blend under a white object. I need to get the image to be just strokes so that the robot can follow them. Somehow I need to get that image to just be simple strokes. I am sure there is some way to make an object, subtract out the white space and then add in a hatch then convert that to primitive line elements. But I have no idea where to begin.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the **Pathfinder** panel.

1. Create your lines.
2. Create your shape, convert it into a compound path and place it above the grouped lines.
3. Select both the lines and the shape and, on the **Pathfinder** panel, click `Outline`. This will effectively 'chop' your lines but won't remove the negative areas.
4. Select all of the resulting paths and add a stroke to them, to make them easier to work with.
5. Now, with the Direct Selection tool (<kbd>A</kbd>) or the Lasso tool (<kbd>Q</kbd>), select all of the paths you don't want and <kbd>Delete</kbd> them.

Alternatively, you can use the **Shaper Tool**.

1. Create your lines.
2. Create your shape, convert it into a compound path and place it above the grouped lines.
3. Now click the **Shaper Tool** in the Tools menu (or hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), and simply draw little scribbles over the segments of the lines that you want to remove.

The nice thing about the Shaper tool is that it's non-destructive – the sections of the lines that you remove are still there (but hidden) until you go `Object > Expand`.

Comment: Not a good idea to outline lines meant for laser cutting as it will make the laser double stroke with a very small gap. @Murenrb Use shapebuilder.

Comment: @joojaa The Outline command in the Pathfinder panel doesn't actually outline the paths, it slices them. Try it yourself and see.

Comment: ahh yes sure my bad. Still it is more work than using shapebuilder which splits and deletes in one go when holding alt.

Comment: Or you could use the new Shaper tool. Actually, I might add that to my answer as another option.

Comment: Shape builder in this instance is better and has a wider user platform.

Comment: Another thing is you could change the first method to include a mention of the lasso tool as this should make it faster, akin to using shaper. But since this is a so complex shape its really tedious anyway.

Comment: Good call, will do.

Comment: I think the pathfinder approach is going to work best for me. It is what I am most familiar with. I am down to the select and delete step. However, I still have the original shape of the parts I want to delete. Is there some way to tell illustrator to select all the components within an area defined by a shape? That seems like it would be a useful tool...

Comment: @Murenrb No, but its possible to make plugin to that effect. I cant release my plugin because it would mean a few thousands of euros of investments to make it work on most platforms and i suspect i would never see that money.

Comment: What is odd is I used the select same appearance tool just to see what would happen after picking a small piece that I needed to delete and it picked all the smaller internal parts. No idea why it picked those ones, but they were all the ones I wanted deleted. Strange right? It's a bit opaque, but happened to be exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

While *pathfinder outline* and *sharper* are nice, they both require you to do quite a lot of pruning. Using shape builder is actually faster here since it requires the least amount of manual dexterity on your part

1. Select the lines you want to participate in the cutting and cut.
2. Activate the shape builder tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Click or drag on line you do not want to keep.

   [image: trim]

   **Image 1**: Trim lines using shape builder.

The nice thing of this is that it does not dice the cutting curve so if you color the cutter with a different color then you can easily select all of them later with **Select → Same → ...**

Other similar related use case:

- [Illustrator: how to reproduce line art](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67372/18306)

Comment: Ok, I played around with this. The major issue is the complexity. It takes illustrator about 10 min to calculate each trim. Then when it is done it has created some truly weird lines. Because of the complexity, it makes it hard to make sure you are alt-drawing the correct line. Then 10 min later you find that you had some weird overlap. its a good thought though! I had no idea how to do this before.

Comment: @Murenrb well it is  dependent on your path complexity. I tried this with a million point world map and a hatch and it didnt take more than 30 seconds. Maybe your running low on memory?

Comment: huh. I am running CS5 on a 2012 MBP with 16GB. I don't think its a memory thing as I am not really doing much else. Maybe I am actually doing it wrong. I will have to give it more work tonight.