# Expanding patterns into complete paths without clipping masks in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, stroke, patterns

I've made a set of seamless patterns in Illustrator, that I want to expand into complete paths. Object>Expand... expands the pattern into separate tiles of the original pattern with a clipping mask (see image below in the outline view).

However, I'm looking for a way that I end up with the paths limited by the shape's boundaries. The purpose is specifically to transform the SVGs into gcode for CNC machine-style plotting, which only works with complete paths.

Any help, tools, plugins, advice appreciated!

[image: Expanding patterns into complete paths]

Comment: Veru long one stroke patterns anbd shape builder. But really there is no very effecient way to do this. Illustrator is not a cam application afer alsls and the concequence of designing for color is that developpers think only in terms of surfaces.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67352/illustrator-how-to-reproduce-line-art/67372#67372

Comment: In many instances you can expand then use **Crop** on the **Pathfinder Panel**. That does depend upon the construction of the actual pattern tile though. i.e. a pattern of strokes won't work well with this method but for a pattern of *shapes* it should work great.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a pattern for this. Make a step blend between two lines at 45°. Expand the blend.

Draw a circle on top with no stroke or fill, select all, and use the Shape Builder tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> while holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> to remove the outer lines. You can also select the circle and delete it after this.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that would be my fallback if I have no other choice. Most of my patterns are mixed into complex multilayered shapes, so I'd rather expand my patterns than redraw them one by one. :)

Comment: @Sulphr Well, it's going to be more difficult if you use a complex pattern. You'd need to expand it and release all the clipping paths that are generated. Then draw a circle, then use the Shape Builder. Unfortunately there is no simple fix for this.

Comment: Yea, was afraid of that. Cheers for thinking a long! 

Comment: @Sulphr its only problematic if yoru pattern does not terminate exactly on the boundary if it does then no problem just delete all mask objects