# Illustrator: Cut Lines at Text Intersections

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I try to cut the lines on the outlines of the text. The expected result is optically what you can see on the picture below, but if I export to SVG the lines are of course still the whole width. I just created a mask, so it looks as it should, but my actual goal is to **really cut** the lines at the intersections, since I need these paths for my Cricut Machine to draw the lines later.

Is there a (simple) way to achieve that w/o having to do it manually on every intersection? I also played around with pathfinder but did not find a way to get the desired result.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image: Example of the starting position and the goal]

Comment: YEah, use shapebuilder. Its sometimes a bit painful but for this case iste easy See near [duplicate question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67352/illustrator-how-to-reproduce-line-art/67372#67372). Thres a more appropriate cklosere duplicate too but couldnt seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general approach that you might find helpful:

> Expand the Strokes:
> Before manipulating the lines, you should expand the strokes so that they become filled shapes. In Adobe Illustrator, you can do this by selecting your paths and going to Object > Expand > Stroke.

**Create Intersecting Shapes**:
Duplicate your expanded paths, and use the Pathfinder tool to create intersecting shapes where you want the lines to appear cut. This might involve creating rectangles or other shapes that overlap with your paths. The goal is to create shapes that will serve as "cut" areas.

**Use Pathfinder to Cut**:
With the overlapping shapes and your expanded paths selected, use the Pathfinder tool to cut the paths at the intersection points. You might need to use the "Minus Front" or "Intersect" option in the Pathfinder panel.

**Adjust Path Order**:
After using the Pathfinder tool, you may need to adjust the order of your paths. Bring forward or send backward paths to ensure that the desired portions appear on top.

**Export as SVG**:
Once you achieve the desired look in Adobe Illustrator, you can export the file as an SVG. Make sure to select the appropriate SVG export settings.