# Creating an optimal quality PNG from PDF for desktop/laptop/mobile screens using ImageMagick - eliminating blur

Tags: pdf, png, image-quality, imagemagick

I use LaTeX to create a PDF which I then crop using PDFCrop.  From there I go to PNG using ImageMagick.  I then insert the PNG into a software program which displays it on my screen - laptop, desktop, or mobile.

Problem: The PNG is not displaying perfectly crisp.

Question: Which parameter values such as DPI/density and scaling should I use in ImageMagick to get a perfectly crisp PNG?

ImageMagick line: magick convert -alpha off -density 600 XXX.pdf -scale 25%% XXX.png

I tried a density of 1000 and scaling down to 12.5% and it was an okay width but it was blurry.

Here is the cropped PDF output from PDFCrop which looks perfectly crisp:

[image: PDFCrop output]

Here is the ImageMagick PNG output using parameters 600 for density and 25% for scaling (good width and height but not perfectly crisp):

[image: IM PNG output]

Here is the output of the software program displaying the PNG on a laptop:

[image]

Comment: You *do* realize the PDF is most likely vector based.. while PNG is *always* raster based.

Comment: No, I did not.  I'm not sure of the difference.  Can that help me in any way?

Comment: I can only use an image file for this application; I cannot use a pdf, for example.

Comment: Is the PNG a logo/icon or a photo?

Comment: @Vikas It's not an logo or icon.  It's a math question which is part of a computerized multiple-choice question creation software package.  It's a workaround since the software does does not support typesetting mathematical symbols - I have to create/enter my questions as images.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your question details. So I feel it's not going to be easy to display crisp text png. Have you tried creating a png of exact size you need and not scaling it? It might make a difference and may appear better.

Comment: No, I have not tried that.  How to tell what size I need?  It's supposed to read as normal text on a screen in like a 12-14pt font size if that helps.

Comment: How are we to optimize if you dont tell us what to optimize for?

Comment: @UngarLinski it will depend on many factors. Your phone or other device dimensions and resolution, how will you display the image in phone.

Comment: @Vikas Using a density of about 150 with no scaling gives the correct height and width but it looks very bad.  Also, wouldn't scaling the image down (shrinking) make it look better and not worse?  I thought a higher density and smaller percent scaling would be doing just that.

Comment: @UngarLinski in my web and mobile experience, I don't think scaling a big image down make it appear better. I was always told to use original size wherever possible. Also, DPI don't matter in screen I think.

Comment: Apparently the software displays the PNG exactly as is and does not scale it or process it more in any way.  So I guess it comes down to the screen it is being viewed on.

Comment: If you have a PDF with an implicit 300ppi density setting for the document, and a vector image, then the vector at that density is 1 "unit." If you set the density of the document now to 600ppi, then the density of the vector is 2x"unit". If you then pass it as a rasterized image format and scale it 25% it is now 1/2x"unit". What you are doing is rendering 2x and then reducing, which is the classic *full scene anti-aliasing" technique. This makes things blurry. What happens when 1/2 the density and emit a raster at 100%?

Answer (score 1):

Scale the original PDF in a proper PDF viewer program so that the wanted formula is shown in the final wanted screen size and take a screenshot. That screenshot is as good as the rendered vector image can be on the screen. If you watch that screenshot in Photoshop or other bitmap image program with high zoom in you'll see it's not at all sharp, it has got just that mathematically decided amount of blur that it looks as sharp as possible on the screen.

To stay in truth in the rendering process vector symbols are moved surgical amounts (=hinted) to make possible to render them well with the least possible amount of blur.

You can see the same if you take a screenshot of this text and watch it in Photoshop in 400% size or bigger.

I do not have ImageMagick, but I guess an exported PNG is as good.

Your problems start when the exported PNG is scaled. PNGs nor other bitmap images cannot be scaled without making them either unsharp or jaggy.

The only way to show the exported bitmaps as sharp is to show them in their original pixel sizes so that every bitmap pixel is shown as a real screen pixel.

Unfortunately I have no idea what application will be used to show your images and how you can guarantee they are not scaled, not at least when shown in default size.

Comment: No its not. Imagemagick indeed does a better job (or atleast does a better job than acrobat, illustrator and photoshop) you just need know how many pixels you need. If you use density and percent scale tgeres no way of knowing the right size.

Comment: See: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58162/how-to-draw-smooth-curved-shapes-in-illustrator/58175#58175

Comment: I'm afraid the improvement achieved by using IM doesn't fix the blurriness caused by scaling a PNG  in an application program.

Comment: Imagemagic uses ghostscript to render the vector graphix to pixels so you can sample it correctly. But actually since moat graphics cards work linear correctly, if you do the same in imagemagick (whiçh op does not do) then the multipixel filter of imagemagic behaves better in resampling than any adobe output.