# How to get rid of pixelated edges in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've created a triangular grid using smart guides and everything looks ok in outline mode.  However when I try to copy and paste to photoshop I continue to get these relic 1px lines at the margins of the triangles. Would love to know how I can get rid of these. They also appear when I export as raster from Illustrator.  [image: pixelated margins]

Comment: Is this zoomed-in in Photoshop? You will always get jagged edges when looking at graphics on a computer screen as all pixels are squares and you do not have diagonal pixels to display information.

Comment: Also see similar question [Illustrator Vector Graphics Appearing Pixellated](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/16028/22318)

Comment: Thanks for the help Andrew.  Yes, this image is zoomed in from Photoshop.  The grid's look fine in Illustrator, however when I copy and paste them as a smart object in Photoshop the lines remain.  There is no stroke applied to the grids, but outline mode suggests everything is lined up correctly.  When I export as a Tiff and bring into Photoshop, everything looks good.  I tried running script to apply the same stroke colour as fill, but the issue persisted.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've also tried exporing as .eps but the lines are still present.  Tiff is fine.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to make a copy of the layer and merge all into a single form and placed under the original, to make some sort of a "background" and it helped.

There are no more transparent strokes in photoshop, but I doubt it's the best alternative.