# Illustrator Aligned to Pixel Grid But Logo Still Fuzzy

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, anti-aliasing, pixelation

I'm trying to create a crisp logo in Illustrator CC, and no matter what I do (have set up web document settings with align to pixel grid), when I go to save my logo as a PNG-24 web document and preview in the browser, the logo appears fuzzy!

Is there something I'm missing about how to make my logo export for my website with a crisp look?

Here is how it exports in PNG-24 format:

[image: Here is how it exports in PNG-24 format]

Here it is with pixel preview:

[image: Here it is with pixel preview]

For Ben: Here is how it looks in Illustrator -> Save for Web -> Preview (PNG) 100%
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Possible answer:
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15828/illustrator-vector-aliasing

Comment: Thanks Ben! I already had "anti-alias' unchecked under Effect -> Document Raster Effect Settings.

Comment: I did notice that the logo appears a lot fuzzier in Firefox than Chrome. Zooming out in firefox helps too. I thought it was just a firefox thing, but then I went to www.squaredspace.com in Firefox and zoomed into their logo.....it's perfect at even 300% zoom! So crisp.

Comment: Another possible duplicate [How to render text pixel-perfectly with subpixel antialising with Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54749/how-to-render-text-pixel-perfectly-with-subpixel-antialising-with-illustrator/54750#54750)

Comment: Have you tried playing with the "Interlaced" and "Type optimized" settings in the Save for web prompt? 
Otherwise, how does it look not in a browser? If you open it at 100% in photoshop or Preview, how does it look?

Comment: @mseager for your last point. They could have either saved the images at 2x or 3x for retina displays. They also could have saved their logo as a SVG which will look good at any size.

Comment: @BenjaminSmith Interlacing seemed to increase file size slightly, so I unchecked it. Type optimized was already set. I've updated my original post with an image of how it looks in AI Preview (Web) at 100%, much better than how it looks in Firefox. I also noticed, zooming out to 80% in Firefox gives the best results.....so it might have something to do with the size of my logo and how the browser is re-adjusting the image.

Comment: @AndrewH Ah! So is that where the magic happens, in that case I need to read up on designing for retina displays and saving as SVG.

Comment: @mseager I would check out this tutorial on CSS-Tricks [Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

Comment: @AndrewH I think that was it! I can't believe I spent 6 hours on this, and all I had to do was save it as .svg :) Why doesn't everyone do this?! The logo looks so much better than a PNG! The logo looks beautiful, crisp, and responds very well to responsive design as well. Thank you so much, sir!!

Comment: @mseager there could be a couple of reasons. 1 reason could be to support for IE8 and below. Some SVG graphics can require thousands of nodes. If you put the SVG code instead of img src then it can look archaic or confusing. I have seen SVG become a lot more popular in recent years.

Comment: @Mseager: SVG is great but browser support isn't 100% yet, so that would be a reason why people are relunctant.

Comment: @BenjaminSmith Thank you for your quick and helpful responses! For beautiful, crisp images, SVG is the future! Thanks again :)

Comment: @AndrewH According to that CSS Tricks document, there are ways to check for browser support with tools like Modernizr. I want to keep the SVG so that is what I will do for providing alternatives for those that can't view it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually tweak this into pixel perfection. With the 'Direct Selection Tool' (A), select each and every anchor point along the paths of the shape, and make sure it is aligned on a grid coordinate. Also, make sure you have View > 'Snap to Pixel' enabled.

Answer (score 0):

We had some problems at work with icons looking fuzzy.
What we did is that we resized all the icons on illustrator as double the size they should be on the browser. When the developer was coding he divided the image by 2 or just set the dimensions manually divided by 2.

The exporting was done the same way "save for web" and with PNG 24.

After that all the icons and images had a crisp look.
You can try that and see if it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the svg file format for logos. You would not get the anti-alias effect as svg does not use pixels but vectors.

Comment: Unless the coordinates for the points fall in fractionary pixels, which is why lines look fuzzy.